# assignment makes integer from pointer without cast in C

Tags: c

This is strcpy function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char *temp1[100];
const char *temp2[100];
int i,j;
const int s1;
const int s2;
char *in[100];
char *stradd(char *str1,char *str2)
{   int s1,s2;
    int i,j;
    *temp1= str1;
    *temp2= str2;
    s1 = strsize(*temp1);
    s2 = strsize(*temp2);
    while(s1<=s2 || s1>=s2)
    {
        for(i=s1,j=0;temp2[j]!='\0';i++,j++)
            *(str1[i]) = *(str2[j]);
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
    return str1;
}

int main()
{
    char in[100];
    printf("Enter a string:\t");
    scanf("%s",in);
    stradd(in,"Hello");
    for(i=0;i<=*(strsize(in));i++)
   {
    printf("\n%c",in[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}



#include <stdio.h>

char* strsize(const char *s)
{   int i,j;
    char *name = s;
    for(i=0;i<=name[i];i++)
        j=i+1;
    return j;
}
```

I get error in `s1` and `s2`, saying assignment makes pointer from integer without  a cast, 
And, I get error in `*(str1[i]) = *(str2[j]);` saying invalid type of argument in unary `*` have `(* int)`. I want to treat the return type of strsize as int how can I make so???

Comment: Hint: what is the return type of `strsize`?

Comment: because you delcare those as ints and try to make them a pointer...

Comment: You appear to be a bit confused with your string declarations, e.g. `const char *temp1[100];` looks wrong.

Comment: `str1[i]` is a `char`, so `*(str1[i])` is like saying `char ch1, ch2; *(ch1) = *(ch2);` You probably mean `str1[i] = str2[j]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your problem seems to be related to the fact that `char* strsize(const char *s)` returns a `char *` but you've assigned it to something declared `int s1`.  How do you want to treat this data -- as a pointer to a string of characters, or as an integer?

Comment: its a pointer house of fun. you are pointing ints to character pointers and then making those ints pointing to character pointers be arrays which are also pointers

Comment: The return type of `strsize` is wrong: `char *strsize` returns `j`, which is an int. Compile with `-Wall -pedantic` and fix all compiler warnings.

Comment: also why do you include the `stdio.h` twice are these two classes or one? https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html

Comment: Another thing: what is up with those globals like `const char *temp1[100];`? Do you even realize what you're declaring? An array of 100 pointers to immutable strings. But you're not assigning them. Why do you need those arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this to copy a string using pointers and functions

```
#include<stdio.h>

void copy_string(char*, char*);

main()
{
    char source[100], target[100];

    printf("Enter source string\n");
    gets(source);
 if (source && source[0] == '\0') {
      printf("source is empty\n");
      return 0;
        }
    copy_string(target, source);

    printf("Target string is \"%s\"\n", target);

    return 0;
}

void copy_string(char *target, char *source)
{
   while(*source)
   {
      *target = *source;
      source++;
      target++;
   }
   *target = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What if target is NULL , in that case your program wont work and if source  string too large to hold in target how you handle this case

Comment: this is just a simple program based on OP and what he was doing with the 100 characters and stuff. no need for complicated memory management @vinayhunachyal